# Change dynamic SQL to Static SQL with order by

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

We have a SP that has a Dynamic SQL and one of the parameters it gets is order by.
when we use the dynamic we can do something like this

```
if @order > 0
BEGIN
SET @ORDERBYSTR = 'ORDER BY ' + cast(@ORDER as varchar(2)) + ' ASC'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @ORDERBYSTR = 'ORDER BY ' + cast(@ORDER as varchar(2)) + ' DESC'
END
```

then the order by is by the column that the number is referring to.

where if we use a static SQL I know I need to do something like this, **but it does not work (sql 2019)**, is there a solution?

```
ORDER BY case when @ORDER > 0 THEN [columnname] ELSE NULL END ASC,
CASE WHEN @ORDER <= 0 THEN [columnname] ELSE NULL END DESC
```

Comment: What does “does not work” mean here? Are you getting an error message? Is it not ordering by what you’d expect?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a *runnable* example illustrating the problem you are working on. Right now your dynamic code seems flawed, and therefore not representing your problem well.  What I mean is, if `@order` was e.g. -1, then you'd end up with `ORDER BY -1 DESC` and that would cause a syntax error. I'm guessing you may be making some simplifications to make the problem clearer but in this case the effect is the opposite (for me anyway). Please consider following suggestions in this Help Center article: [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using `@ORDER` as number, and expecting to be able to order by any column in your result set, you’ll need to have one of those Case expressions for each one. What you have at the moment will only order by the column `columnname`.

But if you have a column called `columnname` then this structure should work for making it sort forwards and backwards.